# Design SQL Server database correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, checkbox

I have simple registration form, but there are 3 checkboxes for example:

```
Name:   [        ]
Email:  [        ]
Pass:   [        ]
What do you like at free time?  
  Reading:    [ ]
  Travelling: [ ]
  Sport:      [ ]
```

As in example above you see "What do you like at free time?" There are 3 checkboxes. There are multiple options, people could check only Reading checkbox or Reading and Travelling or all checkboxes, etc.

How to store it correctly in the database?

For example If I'll create `Users` table in following:

```
CREATE TABLE #User
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(60),
    Email NVARCHAR(60),
    Password NVARCHAR(60),
    FreeTime INT
)
```

I could insert only 1 choice from checkbox. Comma separated solution is bad practice.

I don't know If It's good practice in users table insert multiple records with the same `UserId` to insert all checkboxes values as separate rows?

Or better way to create new table `FreeTime` something like?

```
CREATE TABLE #FreeTime
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    UserId INT,
    Description NVARCHAR(60)
)
```

Comment: create a seperate table and link table, that way you only you can simply insert new rows in the FreeTime table and you can link stuff up without changing schema

Comment: Comma separated values bad practice. Better way is, like you already said, to create another table freetime to store each value separeted per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there!  If you want the data normalized then you will need 3 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE #User
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(60),
    Email NVARCHAR(60),
    Password NVARCHAR(60)
)

CREATE TABLE #FreeTime
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Description NVARCHAR(60)
)

CREATE TABLE #UserFreeTime
(
    UserId INT,
    FreeTimeId INT
)
```

The data from the checkboxes is stored in the `#UserFreeTime` table.

Comment: one more layer (2 tables) if there are to be multiple questions

Comment: yep.  this is what I would do.  will delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a simple user table:

```
CREATE TABLE #User
(
    UserId INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    Email NVARCHAR(255),
    Password varbinary(128)
)
```

Then a composite key table:

```
CREATE TABLE #UserFreeTime
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    FreeTimeID INT NOT NULL
)
```

And the list of free time activities in a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE #FreeTime
(
    FreeTimeID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Description NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using two approaches:

1. Create second table `UserFreeTime` like as following:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE UserFreeTime
   (
     Id INT IDENTITY,
     UserId INT,
     FreeTimeId, 
   )
   ```

   And then define Enums in your code against each option like if you are using C#:

   ```
   public enum {
      Reading,
      Traveling,
      Sport
   }
   ```

   The above enum would be your `FreeTimeId`.
2. In the second approach, you can define the third table including the above two mentioned in approach one.

   This table will have the following structure:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE FreeTime
   (
      Id INT IDENTITY,
      FreeTimeDescription varchar(100),
      IsActive bit, 
   )
   ```

   Instead of using enums, you can store your free time preferences in the above table and can reference its id in `UserFreeTime` table. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an alternative, if your form is never, EVER going to change then adding extra tables is really just trying to design something with flexibility that you don't really need, or attempting to satisfy "good design" principles for no real benefit.

This is the simplest solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #User
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(60),
    Email NVARCHAR(60),
    Password NVARCHAR(60),
    FreeTime_Reading BIT,
    FreeTime_Travelling BIT,
    FreeTime_Sport BIT
)
```

I imagine many people won't like that solution, but it is the simplest for development, also for any reporting, and will have the best performance as it only uses a single table.

Answer (score 0):

The clean model is TrustNo_1's proposal with 3 tables (on relation table between the others).

Richard Hansell and Muhammad Qasim offer a quick and dirty way.

Hard coded columns are heavy to change, but they do the job.

You schould also consider to add check constrain or trigger to prevent wrong data (if so).

For exemple if Sport and read can't be checked together :

```
CREATE TABLE #User
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(60),
    Email NVARCHAR(60),
    Password NVARCHAR(60),
    FreeTime_Reading BIT CHECK (FreeTime_Reading + FreeTime_Sport <> 2),
    FreeTime_Travelling BIT,
    FreeTime_Sport BIT
)
```

You can't use CHECK constrain with a 3 tables model, you will need a trigger to check if a record exist for Sport and for Reading on update and create...